# ASP.NET Core 3 Web Application, Azure App Service, and a ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

NET folks,

I am really new to working with all of these different technologies so pardon me if I am missing some knowledge. In any event, I have a bit of ASP.NET MVC architecture under my belt but I have yet to really grasp the framework, tooling, or what the scaffolding of any given ASP-type web application is doing.

tl;dr;

At the moment, I am working on hosting an ASP.NET CORE (3) web application with Azure and I have setup a plan for the App Service. The project is very simplistic and I just want to get it to run from Azure so it can field requests. The problem, is that it builds fine on my machine but when I publish it to Azure I am met with an HTTP Error 500.0 denoting that I am probably **missing** one of these requirements:

1. The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
2. The in process request handler, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, was not referenced in the application.
3. ANCM could not find *dotnet*.

I think the issue boils down to that I am not doing something with IIS properly either on my local machine or in the cloud.
I will change the logging level of the application as suggested in error message I am getting when I hit the web page AND I have configured a service for Application Insights on Azure so hopefully that will help my case. I have tried a number of StackOverflow suggestions regarding web configs and such but those just regenerate on build.

Any help would be so, so, greatly appreciated as this is a portfolio piece for me and I spent a fair amount of time working on it - I think I may have just missed something basic. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I've added both extensions for .net core 3 (x86 and x64) but still no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately @George, no I never did solve the issue and I had to cancel the App Service on Azure due to a severe lack of funds. I am going to try to just host it locally from my machine one of these days once I can figure out how to do it with IIS and what-not; I have been focusing on mobile development lately.

Comment: I managed it yesterday. I'll add it as an actual answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deploying through visual studio direct to a web app, and configure it to be self-contained, rather than framework dependent.